# Get data of fields in a form triggered by submit-button, pass it to PHP-script

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to code my first extension for Chrome! (Noob-alert)

I want it to save comments I write in some public forums (online newspapers) and send the fields of the form to a PHP-script, which saves them in an SQL database. The PHP/SQL part should be OK since I have some experience with that, but I'm struggling to get the information from the website. The extension should react to the submit-button at the website to get the info of the fields (text/ textarea/ placeholder), open *theupload.php* and pass the data there.

Here is what I have so far:
*manifest.json:*

```json
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Borderify",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Comment Save",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon-19.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon-48.png",
    "96": "icons/icon-96.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.fringo.net/*"],
      "js": ["comments.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

*comments.js* (content file):

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("los");
elem.addEventListener ('click', Warnung);

   function Warnung() {

   var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value; // nach Name suchen
   var Headline = document.getElementById("Headline").value;
   var Text = document.getElementById("Text").value;
   var Kategorie = document.getElementById("Kategorie").value;

   alert (Name + " | " + Headline + " | " + Text + " | " + Kategorie);

 }
```

I got this working for an HTML/JavaScript site. I get the info and open an alert for debugging. But, it won't work for example at diepresse.com, which has an AJAX-environment for sending comments - is that the reason? Can you give me a hint how I can get the extension reacting to the submit-button there to get the values of the fields? In addition, how do I pass them to my website? Do I have to log the network-traffic (like in DevTools), does it work with a content script, or do I need a background script?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the submit event listener instead of the click event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("submit",function(){
 console.log(document.getElementById("comment-field").value)
});
```

And you can pass it to your website through ajax. You don't need the webrequest API for that. It's meant for handling the webrequest like you mentioned but isn't necessary for your case. 
 But you need to specify permission for a cross origin ajax request : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: thx acesmndr for the answer, i ll try that, hope i can ask again then ;) thx jana